# Microsoft Graph Python SDK caching?

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to make a call to 2 differents tenants (A and B). For a weird reason, the call to the second tenant is made to the first tenant (A).

Any idea on how I can avoid this issue?

```
# Get users tenant A
client_secret_credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id='tenant_a',
                                                   client_id='xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
                                                   client_secret=client_secret)

graph_session = GraphSession(client_secret_credentials, scopes)
result_a = graph_session.get('/users')

client_secret_credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id='tenant_b',
                                                   client_id='xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
                                                   client_secret=client_secret)


# Get users tenant B
graph_session = GraphSession(client_secret_credentials, scopes)
result_b = graph_session.get('/users')

print(result_a.content) # users tenant A
print(result_b.content) # users tenant A!
```

Comment: Outside of the SDK, can you repro the issue as well (say, Graph Explorer or POSTMAN)?

Comment: The issue is with the SDK. There is no issue outside de SDK.

Comment: Great. If its related to SDK, make sure that you're using the latest SDK. If you can repro the issue then consider filing the bug at the respective repro - so that i can be addressed. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: It is on its way: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core/issues/85

Comment: Wonderful. Lets hope it will be fixed.